# Blazor wasm cookie authentication

Tags: blazor

I am working on a blazor wasm app and want to authenticate at a WebApi (different base url). My problem is that blazor HttpClient does not respect cookies send by Server. Do you have any hints/idea how to solve this?

In the code below I am trying to attach cookie which I got from the server by the first request (successfull authentication)

Porgram.cs

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomDelegatingHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.myserver.com")).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomDelegatingHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISuncenterService, SuncenterService>();

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
```

CustomDelegatingHandler.cs looks like this

```
    private readonly IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
    public CustomDelegatingHandler(IJSRuntime jSRuntime) : base()
    {
        JSRuntime = jSRuntime;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        const string prm = "cookie";
        string cookie = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorExtensions.GetCookie", new[] { prm 
  });
        Console.WriteLine($"{prm}: {cookie}");
        request.Headers.Add(prm, cookie);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Yes. Final CustomDelegatingHandler.cs looks like this: 
    public class CustomDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
And I added custom domain to my heroku host (I was hosting it on heroku), without adding custom domain it was working only with Firefox, not chromium.

Comment: This info about chromium browsers might be usefull too: https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :) On my side, I switched to JWT (Json Web Token) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Credentials) option on the request. The credentials option, as explained by the MDN link, controls whether the browser sends cookies on cross-origin requests - such as requests to your (different base url) WebAPI:

> The credentials read-only property of the Request interface indicates
> whether the user agent should send cookies from the other domain in
> the case of cross-origin requests.

The C# way of doing this for a request is:

```
request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);
```

The three choices for the option are Omit, SameOrigin, or Include:

> `Omit` advises the browser never to send credentials (such as cookies
> or HTTP auth headers).

> `SameOrigin` advises the browser to send credentials (such as cookies
> or HTTP auth headers) only if the target URL is on the same origin as
> the calling application.

> `Include` advises the browser to send credentials (such as cookies or
> HTTP auth headers) even for cross-origin requests.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I added request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include); to my CustomDelegatingHandler in SendAsync method, but browser stil does not send cookie

Comment: Are you running your debugging HTTP or HTTPS? If it's http, ensure the cookie doesn't have the Secure flag set (you can see this in the browser dev tools when looking at the cookie). If you're already https, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: yes I'm already on https. Thank you for your help